# waiting for all go routines to finish

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

First time with go, and trying to get go routines and `WaitGroups` working.

I have a CSV file with 100 rows of data. (101 including header)

I have the following simple code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    numRows := 0

    waitGroup := sync.WaitGroup{}
    file, _ := os.Open("./data.csv")

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Scan() // to read the header

    for scanner.Scan() {
        err := scanner.Err()

        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            panic(err)
        }

        waitGroup.Add(1)

        go (func() {
            numRows++
            waitGroup.Done()
        })()
    }

    waitGroup.Wait()
    file.Close()

    fmt.Println("Finished parsing ", numRows)
    fmt.Println("Elapsed time in seconds: ", time.Now().Sub(start))
}
```

When i run this, the `numRows` output fluctuates between 94 and 100 each time. I'm expecting it to be 100 each time. If i run the same code on a CSV of 10 rows of data, it outputs `10` each and every time.

Seems to me like the final few go routines aren't finishing in time.

I've tried the following which have failed:

- using a `CsvReader` instead of a `Scanner`
- moving `waitGroup.Add(1)` to underneath the anonymous func
- moving the anonymous func out into a package-level scope func (and passed things round using ptrs)

What am i missing?

Comment: Run it under the race detector :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you do with this code:

```
for scanner.Scan() {
    err := scanner.Err()

    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        panic(err)
    }

    waitGroup.Add(1)

    go (func() {
        numRows++
        waitGroup.Done()
    })()
}
```

Really all the work is done in one main goroutine and only `numRows` increment uses separate goroutines. I think this could be simplified to simple increment:

```
for scanner.Scan() {
    err := scanner.Err()

    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        panic(err)
    }
    numRows++
}
```

If you want to simulate parallel parsing and pipelining you may use channels. Make only one goroutine responsible for counter increment.  Every time when another goroutine wants to increment counter - it sends a message to that channel.

https://play.golang.org/p/W60twJjY8P

Comment: No doubt it could be simplified, but I don't think that's the point of the question.

Comment: yep, just shared some ideas how to serialize access with channels

Comment: ahh this makes sense. my code is pretty flimsy, but the point was just me getting to grips with concurrency in go so this has pushed me in the right direction. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It's not safe to modify a single variable simultaneously in different goroutines. Some of your updates to `numRows` will be lost, and occasionally your program may crash.

Either protect your `numRows` variable with a mutex, or use one of the [atomic](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) functions to do your addition atomically:

```
var numRows int32

// ...

    go (func() {
        atomic.AddInt32(&numRows, 1)
        waitGroup.Done()
    })()
```

Comment: now you've said that, it makes sense. i think i'm starting to understand goroutines a little more now. thanks for the heads up about atomic functions as well.